# How to remove the preview image on video and picture files in folders?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I would like to have that setup like in Windows where just the file names show when browsing in folders, and not any small picture of the image or video preview of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nautilus

1. Go to **Edit > Preferences > Preview**
2. Here change  *always* to *never* for **Show text in icons** and **Show thumbnails**

[image: File Management Preferences dialog]